# MongoDB cannot call method 'aggregate' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to pull the lowest score in an array. My error is cannot call method 'aggregate' of undefined. The aggregate method is defined in mongodb, I even foud it, and db.students is certainly defined. I can't seem to find where i am going wrong.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient // Driver for connecting to MongoDB

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school', function(err, db) {
      if(err) throw err;

x = db.students.aggregate( [{ "$unwind":"$scores" },{"$match":{"scores.type":"homework"}},{ "$group":{"_id":"$_id","minscore":{"$min":"$scores.score" }}} ] )

x.result.forEach(function(doc) {
   db.students.update( { "_id": doc._id }, 
                       { "$pull": { "scores" : { 
                                          "score":doc.minscore, 
                                          "type":"homework"
                       } } } 
   );
});

});
```

I have that feeling that I am getting tunnel vision from staring at this for too long, thanks for looking over it for me with a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: db.students is not a valid object. You need to get access to the collection via db.collection('students').aggregate(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use the node driver, you can't use the same syntax as you would in the Mongo shell. It should be like this:

```
db.collection('students').aggregate();
```

[Here's the reference.](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect)

Comment: Wow this is a very concise, well delivered answer and makes sense after having looked under the hood. On top of that you answered the question so quickly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Also, if you are just using a js file to execute more complex Mongo operations, you can run them directly in the Mongo shell, which you wouldn't use the Node driver and would write the request exactly how you would in the shell, either from the shell or when start up the shell from the command line. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#execute-a-javascript-file